# Change destination for uploaded files to match attached files on O365 Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-list

We have an Office 365 Sharepoint list that allows attachments to items.

The "Actions < Attach file" option stores those attachments in an Attachments folder, under the list item ID# and file name of the attachment.

That's AWESOME. The path looks something like this:

```
http://sharepointsitename/lists/listname/Attachments/autoassignedlistitemnumber/capture.png
```

Unfortunately, a number of users are using the "insert" or "uploadpicture" option to insert a picture or other file into the list item. It doesn't offer the Attachments folder as an option, so most people seem to be picking the Images folder, and they're not renaming their snipping tool images, so they're all trying to upload "capture.png" to their items. Each one overwrites any previous versions, replacing the images in the other items.

Is there a way to set the upload/insert options to send those files to the same Attachments folder, under the specific list item #, so our users aren't overwriting one another's screenshots? Telling these users "rename your files so they have unique names" isn't a great approach, because most of them will not remember to do that. Automating the process would be more friendly to our end users.